# Method returns null when I expect an object

Tags: objective-c

I have a method in a class called `GameManager` that I have written in Objective-C. The class has an array of questions declared as follows:

```
@interface GameManager()
   @property(strong, nonatomic)NSMutableArray* questions;
@end

-(id)init{
  if (self == nil){
    self = [[GameManager alloc] init];
    self.questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  }
  return self;
}

//The method:
-(Question*)getNextQuestion{

  for (Question* q in _questions)
  {
    NSLog(@"%@",q.answerText);  //Prints out the expected text for each question
  }
  Question* toret = [[Question alloc] init];
  toret = _questions[1];

  NSLog(@"About to return %@", toret.questionText); //prints "About to return (null)"
  return toret;
}
```

Now this method is called from a view controller which has the `GameManager` declared as a member. Here's the declaration and call:

```
@interface QuizController ()
  @property(strong, nonatomic) GameManager* manager;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   _manager = [[GameManager alloc] init];
   [self.manager setupGame];
   _questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   _questions = [_manager getAllQuestions];
}
- (IBAction)nextClicked:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"Next Clicked");

   if (_manager.nQuestionsAnswered < _manager.nQuestionsInGame){
    _manager.nQuestionsAnswered = _manager.nQuestionsAnswered+1;
    NSLog(@"Number of questions OK");
   }
   Question* next = [[Question alloc] init];
   next = [_manager getNextQuestion];
   if (next == nil)
    NSLog(@"next is nil!");

   NSLog(next.questionText);
   [ self.questionText setText:_questions[_manager.nQuestionsAnswered]];
```

}

Here's the Question class, it's pretty simple:

Question.m:
    #import "Question.h"

```
@implementation Question

-(id)init {
if (self == nil){
    self = [[Question alloc] init];
}
return self;
}

-(BOOL) checkAnswer:(NSString *)userAnswer
{
   return [_answerText isEqualToString:userAnswer];
}
```

@end

Question.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Question : NSObject

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *questionText;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *answerText;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *wrong1Text;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *wrong2Text;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *wrong3Text;

- (BOOL) checkAnswer:(NSString*)userAnswer;

@end
```

I'm almost certain I'm making a simple mistake that I don't see but if anyone could shed some light onto why I keep returning `null` from `getNextQuestion` I'd be very grateful!

**Update**

I've added some more code above to try to provide some more information. Having used the debugger it seems that the `NSMutableArray _questions` is `nil` in my instance of `GameManager _manager`. I don't understand how this can be the case so I've added the code where I call `init` functions in both the `GameManager` and `QuizController` classes.

Comment: Try placing a breakpoint in your `getNextQuestion` method and stepping through to see exactly when `toret` is assigned to `nil`.

Comment: try changing where you get the question from array to this:
`toret = (Question*)[_questions objectAtIndex:1];`

Comment: Where do you create and set the `manager` property of your `QuizController`?

Comment: Why do you do this in `getNextQuestion`: `Question* toret = [[Question alloc] init];`?

Answer (score 0):

These two lines:

```
Question* toret = [[Question alloc] init];
toret = _questions[1];
```

can be condensed into this:

```
Question* toret = _questions[1];
```

(Note that you are fetching the 2nd object in the array, not the first one)

Now, your `NSLog()` line will return nil in two cases:

1. `toret.questionText` is not initialized,
2. `toret` is nil, which will always be the case if your `_questions` array has only one question.

In case it was a typo, the indexes in arrays start from 0, not from 1, so to fetch the first object in array, use this:

```
Question* toret = _questions[0];
```

or this

```
Question* toret = [_questions firstObject];
```

Comment: This answer is not quite correct. Point 2 is wrong. If the `_questions` array only has one object, the app would crash. The likely cause for seeing `nil` in the log is because `_manager` is `nil`.